# Render ipcam-view stream into SurfaceTexture -Android

Tags: android, mjpeg, google-vr

I have `GVRView` that displays an OpenGL Surface, and I have video stream I want to display on it.

The ipcam-view uses uses `MjpegSurfaceView`, how can I extend it to make it render to openGL surface that GVRView can display?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the texture from the each video frame and draw it on GvrView. I'm not sure this would be helpful but I made [a camera preview example uisng GoogleVR SDK](https://github.com/kjw0723/GoogleVR-CameraExample). It uses SurfaceTexture to use camera preview image as OpenGL ES texture and draw texture with shader.

Comment: I have created similar app, but I don't know how to extend the renderer